# How can I reintroduce username an password on git using fedora?

Tags: git, github, console, fedora

I've a big trouble, since 4 hour's I tried to introduce, my credentials on git, but every single time I try, the command line give me this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xj4J.png)

But it don't let me introduce the credentials, and all because I forgot that I had to put my Access Token, now I can't do anything, just because I can't push my work on git, a simple solution is changing the repo to a public one, but the code is not finish...

Please somebody help me

To find a solution to my little problem

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve your problem, you first need insight into what is occurring.

So to do that, you should enable SSH debugging:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -vvv"
```

Then run your `git clone` again. This time, it will show you a lot more information. You can create a new StackOverflow question with those details.

When you are finished debugging, run this command to turn off SSH debugging:

```
 git config --global core.sshCommand ""
```

---

All of that said, you probably just don't have SSH keys installed properly: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: The OP uses **HTTPS**